# In Xamarin Forms running on Mac OS. How can I access the asset catalog to add new icons in iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've not been able to find anything in the document except for examples from VS running on the PC.  Can someone tell me how I can add icons to the asset catalog with VS running on macOS for Xamarin forms?

[image]

Comment: there are tabs for VS Mac and VS PC in each doc page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=macos#managing-icons-with-asset-catalogs

Comment: Possibly it's different for XF as my info.plist screen does not look the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under iOS project, double click on 'Assets.xcassets' and change the existing 'AppIcon' icons or Add a new Asset and attach the icons. Then, double click on Info.plist. Go to 'Application' tab, and change the 'Source' of 'App Icons' to the asset that you just created.